# How to initialize the interface callback in fragment if i overriding the interface in another fragment not in activity

Tags: java, android

I'm having a `BottomSheetfragment` where I have written an interface `callback` method and I overriding this methods in some of my activity and in some `fragment`, but not able to initialize the same interface for both `(activity_fragment)` in `onAttach()` method of `BottomSheetfragment`.

```
 @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            onVariationChanged = (onVariationChanged) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement onVariationChangedListener");
        }
    }
```

I have tried this but it throws  Class cast Exception.

```
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            onVariationChanged = (onVariationChanged) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement onVariationChangedListener");
        }
    }
```

> java.lang.ClassCastException:

Comment: Post all code of this class

Answer (score 0):

Implement your activity with  onVariationChanged Interface.

```
MainActivity implements onVariationChanged {}
```

and update your code with this

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            onVariationChanged = (onVariationChanged) getActivity();
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement onVariationChangedListener");
        }
    }




@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
         onVariationChanged = (onVariationChanged) getActivity();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement onVariationChangedListener");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your activity which you are attaching `BottomSheetfragment` needs to conform to the `onVariationChanged` interface(`YourActivity implements onVariationChanged...{`. 
you can avoid try / catch with the following:

```
 @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if(context instanceof onVariationChanged){
           this.onVariationChanged = (onVariationChanged)context;
        }else{
        //handle case when your activity is not castable to onVariationChanged interface
        }

    }
```

Comment: first of all im attaching BottomSheetfragment in another fragment not in activity sir and ihave overidden the method already

Comment: how do you instantiate BottomSheetfragment? you need to pass supportFragmentManager from activity, not child fragment manager from fragment.